# Are there cases in modern JavaScript where arrow functions cannot be used where "bind" was previously used?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, this, bind, arrow-functions

I'm still learning the ins and outs of `bind` and arrow functions.

It seems that wherever we used to use `bind` we should now use an arrow function instead, though I haven't yet seen it spelled out exactly that way.

So I'm wondering if this is true or if there are some cases where we should still use `bind` even though an arrow function might work, or some cases where an arrow function will not work and `bind` is still the only way to do what you want.

Or, if I'm totally off, in new JS code, when should I prefer an arrow function and when should I prefer `bind`?

Comment: well, if you ever want to bind to something other than `this`, then you'll need to use `.bind`. Doesn't come up often.

Comment: I've seen cases where you might want to bind things *in addition to* `this`, in which case an arrow function still works and you just pass those as additional arguments. I haven't yet seen `bind` used without `this` at all but it's definitely possible so I guess it's done occasionally (-:

Comment: Voting to re-open. None of the answers on the other question list any use cases for using bind over arrow functions at all. The answers here are unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see 2 advantages:

**Partial Application:**

The bind method can be used to pre-set a function's arguments; it sort of lets you create a sub-function of a function (not literally, behind-the-scenes, there will be only one function) by passing an argument before making the call, so that this argument you have preset will be used for all invocations of the function returned by bind. @Charlie_H has already explained this, but I am going to provide an example as well:

```
function foo(bar, baz) {
return bar + baz;   
}

var sub_foo = foo.bind(Object.create(null), 20);

console.log(sub_foo(60));
console.log(sub_foo(120));
```

So as you can see in the above example, the `bind` method allowed me to create what you could call a sub-function off of `foo`, this function will always use `20` for its first parameter.

Now again, don't let my poor wording misguide you, `bind` does not actually create a new function! behind-the-scenes, the original function will be used, the only thing is `bind` will perform some of its magic so that the parameter you passed to `bind` is always used. I am using the word "sub-function" because it makes the whole thing easier to understand.

**Ability to bind the `this` of the target function to whatever object you want:**

With fat-arrow functions, the `this` of the fat-arrow function will always be bound to the `this` of the enclosing scope; with bind, you can bind the target function's `this` to any object you want:

```
function foo() {
return this.baz;
}

var bar = foo.bind({baz: "Hell yeah!"});

bar(); // "Hell yeah!"
```

Moreover, the `this` binding of fat-arrow functions is not overridable, this is a subtle detail but still useful.

One more thing i want to add, in the book You Don't Know JS: this & Object Prototypes, Kyle Simpson says that you should not use fat-arrow functions to get around `this` complexities, which sort of bends JavaScript's `this` rules, since their usage roots back to the `var self = this` pattern, and that pattern's usage stems from a lack of understanding of JavaScript's `this` behavior. Short version: he prefers `bind`. 
I don't see anything with using fat-arrow functions though, IMO they even make code more readable since just by looking at them you can see what the developer is trying to do and how they've used that, meanwhile, with `bind`, you don't know exactly what the developer is trying to do and why they're doing it until you look at `bind`'s first argument. I recommend fat-arrow functions where you want the `this` of the fat-arrow function to be bound to the current scope's `this`, and `bind` when you want it bound to something else.

If you don't understand parts of my answer, ask me and I will try to elaborate in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

I see an added advantage of the `bind` method since it can be partially applied.

```
function list() {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
}

var list1 = list(1, 2, 3); // [1, 2, 3]

// Create a function with a preset leading argument
var leadingThirtysevenList = list.bind(null, 37);

var list2 = leadingThirtysevenList(); 
// [37]

var list3 = leadingThirtysevenList(1, 2, 3);
// [37, 1, 2, 3]
```

(courtesy [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind))

I consider arrow functions for situations where a shorthand syntax is handy and the execution context should not be its own.